# Reading a 4 band image with rasterio

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, rasterio

I am trying to view a tif satellite image which has 4 bands. I want to remove the last band (NIR) and view the RGB image only, so I am trying to split the NIR from the rest of the image. Here is my code

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from rasterio import plot
import numpy as np
#to display RGB
dataset = rasterio.open('2.tif')
%matplotlib inline
plot.show(dataset.read([1,2,3]), cmap="gray")
#to display just the red band
%matplotlib inline
plot.show(dataset.read(4), cmap="gray")
```

I provided a screen shot of the code and the output I am getting [image: screen shot]

Displaying just 1 band seems fine, but any idea why I keep seeing an image with a yellow and white color scheme when I try to display RGB bands together? I thought it's a cmap issue at the beginning, but even when I add 'cmap="gray"' the color of the image remains the same.

Comment: You might get better response on https://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you try calling `plot.show` on just the opened *.tif file rather than the reading data in? For example `plot.show(dataset)`